# How do I make a block in Minecraft face where the player faces?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I am coding my first minecraft mod. I made a steel beam and it always faces north. I wanted to make it face whatever direction the player faces. I have tried multiple things, such as:

```
@Override
    public IBlockState withRotation(IBlockState state, Rotation rot)
    {
        return state.withProperty(FACING, rot.rotate((EnumFacing)state.getValue(FACING)));
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    public IBlockState getStateForPlacement(World world, BlockPos pos, EnumFacing facing, float hitX, float hitY,
            float hitZ, int meta, EntityLivingBase placer, EnumHand hand) {
        return super.getStateForPlacement(world, pos, facing, hitX, hitY, hitZ, meta, placer, hand).withProperty(FACING, placer.getHorizontalFacing());
    }
```

Neither of these worked. I used MrCrayfish's model maker, in which the sides are directional. I don't know if this is important, but I decided to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Override `IForgeBlock#getStateForPlacement` and return the **default state** of the block obtained by `Block#getDefaultState`.

An example of this would be:

```
@Override
public IBlockState getStateForPlacement(World world, BlockPos pos, EnumFacing facing, float hitX, float hitY, float hitZ, int meta, EntityLivingBase placer) {
    return this.getDefaultState().withProperty(FACING, placer.getHorizontalFacing());
}
```

You would also need to override Block#createBlockState to return a BlockStateContainer containing the direction property:

```
@Override
protected BlockStateContainer createBlockState() {
    return new BlockStateContainer(this, new IProperty[] {FACING});
}
```